# unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.system-extension' for platform macosx (in target SimpleFirewallExtension))

Tags: macos-catalina, macos-system-extension

I Am trying to build and run FirewallExtension sample app from 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/filtering_network_traffic
on catalina beta version,
but getting error

unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.system-extension' for platform macosx

using xcode version 10.2
any idea what is missed here? 
is some specific xcode version is needed here?

Answer (score 2):

System Extensions are new to macOS 10.15 and unknown to Xcode 10. You'll need to use Xcode 11 to develop them.

Comment: Tried with Xcode 11, but getting same error:
MacOS Deployment Target is set to 10.15, but range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is from 10.6 to 10.14.99.

Comment: I've just downloaded the sample code you linked and tried building it in both Xcode 11 Betas 1 (11M336w) and 2 (11M337n) and in each case, after selecting my code signing team, it built first time. This is both with running Xcode on Mojave and Catalina. I'm guessing opening the project in Xcode 10 must have trashed the project file. I suggest redownloading it.

Comment: ok thanks, I get an error 'app identifier "com.example.apple-samplecode.SimpleFirewall.SimpleFirewallExtension" can not be registered to your developer team.' Do I need to register this app in deveoper team even for building it?